# unable to send data using CURLOPT_POST to other php file

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am new to php , i am trying to get data from a website using curl (scraping),

UNABLE to get data from index.php to data.php, using CURLOPT_POST.. what am i doing wrong..?

- [followed this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YdBrkDdn0M)

**index.php**

```
<?php
$data = array("name"=>"john","age"=>31);
$string = http_build_query($data);

echo $string;

$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/scrap_practise/data.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php 
echo 'finlly in'; // this never echos 
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['age'])){
    $db = new Mysqli("localhost","root","","mydb");
    $name = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $age = (int) $_POST['age'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO data SET data='$name,$age'";
        $db->query($query);

}

?>
```

Comment: assign curl in variable `$result = curl_exec($ch);` and print result `print_r($result);` to check errors, but your code works fine i think problem is with your host name it is `localhost` not  `loclhost`

Comment: Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, Your Url);`

Comment: @manjeet barnala- no, but it's not even echoing the code in data.php , the first line in data.php is `echo 'finlly in' .,, it doesnt show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you have to update you `index.php` script with these line of code.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$data = array("name"=>"john","age"=>31);
$string = http_build_query($data);

echo $string;

$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/scrap_practise/data.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch))
{ 
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
} 
curl_close($ch);

// to see the return result uncomment the below line code.
//print_r($result);
?>
```

For more options or function reference see this link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Hope this will help to resolve your issue !!

Comment: bro, that worked, i can now see the echos that are inside data.php, but it didnt make any sense to me. how..? how an if statements makes a difference .. plus am still not able to see data in database (although i'll work it around, help in that case will be appreciated )

Comment: i thinks it because of that print_r($result);

Comment: @Bawa, function `curl_exec()` returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, it will return the result on success, `FALSE` on failure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I hope it will work for you...

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/scrap_practise/data.php';

$data = array("name"=>"john","age"=>31);

$string = http_build_query($data);

echo $string;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result) ; 

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

In data.php file

```
<?php 
echo 'finlly in'; // this never echos 
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['age']))
{
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

This will Output :

```
finlly in
Array
(
    [name] => john
    [age] => 31
)
```

Comment: this worked too bro , but i can only mark one answer right. :) thanks for helping .